# Searching through a file takes forever when action is phrased in a certain way

Tags: haskell, optimization, io

I have a textfile containing about 45k words and I want to check some simple property about the words.

Here is the body of my program

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Set as Set

vowel x = elem x "aeiou"

nontrivial w = not $ null [x | x <- w, vowel x]

toPigLatin :: String -> String
toPigLatin word
    | vowel (head word) = word ++ "ay"
    | otherwise = let (v, c) = span (not . vowel) word in
                                if c == "" then word
                                else c ++ v ++ "ay"


pigExists :: String -> Set.Set String -> Bool
pigExists word set = Set.member (toPigLatin word) set
```

But here are two possible ways to write the `main` action:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    allWords <- words <$> readFile "/tmp/linuxwords2" --https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/linuxwords
    let pigHits = filter (\word -> nontrivial word && pigExists word (Set.fromList allWords)) allWords
    sequence_ $ map putStrLn pigHits
```

and

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    allWords <- words <$> readFile "/tmp/linuxwords2" --https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/linuxwords
    let pigHits = filter (\word -> nontrivial word && pigExists word (Set.fromList allWords)) allWords
    putStrLn $ unlines pigHits
```

I have tried compiling with `ghc -O2` and the former works fine, but the latter takes forever to produce an answer.

What is the real difference between these two styles? In general, how should I write efficient code that involves IO?

This problem was discussed first in [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/184604/106329)

Comment: The second should produce output as it becomes available if the output device is unbuffered or line buffered. How are you testing?

Comment: Could not reproduce. Both programs take 1.5s on my machine when run on `/usr/share/dict/words`, 0.1s on your file.

Comment: Unrelated: I'd move `(Set.fromList allWords)` outside the lambda, otherwise we reconstruct the set for every word. E.g. `let setWords = Set.fromList allWords ; pigHits = filter (\word -> .... setWords) ...`

Comment: The only difference between the two programs is `sequence_ . map putStrLn` (which is just `mapM_ putStrLn`) vs. `putStrLn . unlines`. Both of these programs have identical performance. Their behaviour *might* differ depending on how your terminal does buffering.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the problem in GHC 7.10.2.  Using GHC 8.2.2 the problem is not present.  Solution: upgrade your compiler.

It isn't surprising to see the second version performing worse - after all it is creating a rather long linked list by concatenating a large set of strings - this takes time and memory.  The first version does not make the intermediate list at the cost of many (relatively fast) calls to `putStrLn`.  EDIT: This wasn't ment to say it should take *this* long.  I see now that output list, which I redirected to null, is extremely short.  This is certainly a bug in the older GHC.

Comment: The set of strings that the program prints is not large, it just has 8 elements.

Comment: I see. A bug, quite simply.

Comment: This bug seems to exist as recently as 8.0.2.  You'll want to use 8.2.x.